# Sorting file size in table sorter jQuery?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I will have file sizes in a column in `B, MB, GB, TB`. I am using jQuery tablesorter. Right now I am using table sorter as:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // call the tablesorter plugin 
        if ($("#product-table tbody td").length > 0){
        $("table").tablesorter({ 
            // sort on the first column and third column, order asc 
            sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]] 
        }); 
        }
    });
```

How can I make the column sortable by file size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [metric parser](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-metric.html) for tablesorter.